# mongodb update schema for client side encryption field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an existing collection with CSFE, and I want to change it WITHOUT dropping the collection.

I've tried the below code, but I'm getting:

```
TypeError: command not supported for auto encryption: collMod
    at AutoEncrypter.encrypt (/Users/Goldy/apps/node-mongoose-ts-boilerplate/node_modules/mongodb-client-encryption/lib/autoEncrypter.js:241:36)
    at CryptoConnection.command (/Users/Goldy/apps/node-mongoose-ts-boilerplate/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:787:19)
```

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import { ClientEncryption } from "mongodb-client-encryption"

import db from "../src/db"

export default async function setupUsersEncryption() {
  const client = mongoose.connection.getClient()
  const encryption = new ClientEncryption(client as any, {
    ...db.getAutoEncryption(),
  })
  const _key = await encryption.createDataKey("local")

  // mongoose.connection.db.runCommand({
  mongoose.connection.db.command({
    collMod: "users",
    validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        properties: {
          // Automatically encrypt the 'name' property
          name: {
            encrypt: {
              bsonType: "string",
              keyId: [_key],
              algorithm: "AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512-Deterministic",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you using community edition? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/security-client-side-encryption/#introduction

Comment: no, I'm using Atlas directly

Answer (score 0):

The encryption schema is a connection option, not a document validator:

From https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/csfle/quick-start/#create-the-mongoclient:

```
const secureClient = new MongoClient(connectionString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  autoEncryption: {
    keyVaultNamespace,
    kmsProviders,
    schemaMap: YOUR_ENCRYPTION_SCHEMA_GOES_HERE,
    extraOptions: extraOptions,
  },
});
```

I agree it's a bit confusing since they use json schema for both validators and encryption, but it kinda makes sense since both describes how to deal with documents.

Validator's schema is stored as collection metadata serverside for mongo to validate documents on writes.

Encryption's schema is stored on application level clientside for driver to encrypt data before sending it over the wire. It's why it's called clientside encryption.

If you want to use mongoose connection, you need to add the `autoEncryption` parameter to the `mogoose.connect` command.

There is no need to drop or modify you collection in any way. You may need to modify documents though. Assuming they are not encrypted yet, you need to fetch them to the client, apply encryption, and save back to the database.